# YADCF multi_select filter dropdown element matching as exact match or startsWith match

Tags: jquery, django, yadcf

I'm using yadcf with server side processing in django:

The initialisation of the filter I'm trying to work with is like this :

```
 { column_number : 4, filter_type: "multi_select", select_type:"select2", sort_as:"none", filter_match_mode:"exact" },
```

Basically I want the search value entered by the user to be matched with the elements in the drop down list as a "startsWith" or an "exact" match but currently they are being matched as "contains".

This is related to just the matching in the dropdown list and the value entered in the input box on top and not the actual filtering of the table.

and the kind of behaviour i'm looking for can be found here : https://select2.github.io/examples.html#matcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my work around for the issue, not really sure if this is the right way of doing it but it works for my application -

```
        $.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/compat/matcher'], 
      function (oldMatcher) {
              function matchStart (term, text) {
                  if (text.toUpperCase().startsWith(term.toUpperCase())) {
                  return true;
               }
            return false;
      }


    yadcf.init(dt_table, [
    {
      column_number : 0, 
      filter_type:"multi_select",
      select_type:"select2", 
      select_type_options:{ 
         matcher:oldMatcher(matchStart)}
          },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Select2 options could be passed from yadcf by using the [select_type_options](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/d5dba790602738a234d4629596b1005c1d9fab56/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L224), like this:

```
{
    column_number: 2,
    select_type: 'select2',
    select_type_options: {
        width: '150px',
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1 // remove search box
    }
}
```

If needed you can pass a function too just declare a variable and set it with a function, I suggest you to try it on a test page containing a slect2 box only (without datatables / yadcf) after that move your code to yadcf column init

Since you are using `serverSide` you must know that your entire filtering logic should be implemented in your server side.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help! I tried assigning the function to a variable and call it on matcher but that didn't seem to work so I did a work around and defined my yadcf.init code inside a function that imports the old select2 adapter.